# error 500 on .htaccess while using url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm getting

an error 500 on my werver

http://www.sp-batiment.com/spb

while trying to url rewrite,

but I did not have any trouble on localhost.

Below is my .htaccess

```
php_flag output_buffering on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php/p/([^/.]+)(\.html)?$ ?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I guess something may be wrong, but I did not find issue since 2 days,

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing wrong here, check your Apache error.log. mod_rewrite might not be enabled.

Comment: Can you check your apache log for errors ?

Comment: yes, there is no error there